# Why can't you get an E on a test in the United States?

Tags: united-states, exams

So, in testing in the USA, an A is the best score you can get. Then comes B, which most students desire, and then comes a C, where you're on the verge of shattering your gradebook by getting a bad grade. Then there's D (even worse), and an F, where you will surely be very ashamed of yourself. Then, there's this alphabetical pattern, A, B, C, D, and then F. But where's E? Why isn't there an E in it?

In an answer given, I want a historical explanation of this question that tells how these letter grades popped up, and why E dropped out (or was never included) in the USA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A possible explanation I have seen that it is trivial to manipulate when an E is there. If you get an F, simply add one bar and you got an E.

Comment: For what it's worth, a lot of schools (particularly primary/secondary schools) don't even use "D" any longer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I haven't located a super reliable source, but from [Slate](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2010/08/how-come-schools-assign-grades-of-a-b-c-d-and-f-but-not-e.html):

> The earliest record of a letter-grade system comes from Mount Holyoke College in Massachusetts in 1897. [...] The lowest grade at Mount Holyoke was an E, which represented failure. [...] One year later, administrators changed the failing grade to F and tweaked the other letters. The new scale offered better symmetry, since each grade represented five points, with scores below 75 resulting in failure. [...] Over the next two decades, variations on the letter-grade system spread across the country and into primary and secondary schools. It’s hard to put a date on the end of the E, but it was gone from most colleges by 1930. Apparently, some professors worried that students would think the grade stood for “excellent,” since F stood for “failure.”

Basically, four grades (and plus/minuses) and a fail option seemed to work out well from the instructors' perspective, and F was picked up for "fail."

Possibly the concern over "E" was affected by the ESNU system (according to an uncited [paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_the_United_States#The_E-S-N-U_system) on Wikipedia):

> At one time (until roughly the mid-20th century), the most popular grading system in the United States used four letters, which ranked in descending order:
>
> - E (Excellent)
> - S (Satisfactory)
> - N (needs improvement; "NI" was also used interchangeably)
> - U (unsatisfactory)

Comment: Also worth nothing the "ESNU" system: excellent/satisfactory/needs improvement/unsatisfactory, which is probably the actual reason for the concern about E being misleading.

Comment: Okay. That actually makes a lot of sense when you think about it, since in one system, E means failure, and in another means excellent. It can be quite confusing.

Comment: I've also seen Excellent, Good, Fair, Unsatisfactory in primary grades. Which might muddy up what both E and F mean.

Comment: Maybe another concern was that an F could be easily turned into an E by a cheating student, if both existed in the same grading system, when grades were recorded in paper. I do not have a source, though; I am only speculating.

Comment: The use of the past tense in the Wikipedia quote there seems to imply that ESNU is no longer in use, but it is the norm in lower-elementary schools (roughly K–2 ish) around where I'm from

Comment: @Elizabeth Henning: *I've also seen Excellent, Good, Fair, Unsatisfactory in primary grades.* --- My first few years of elementary school grades had this format. I'm not sure for how many years (I thought I knew where my school report cards were and was going to find out more definitively, but they're not in the first, and only, place I looked), but this was in the mid to late 1960s.

Comment: in NZ E does stand for Excellent (technically Excellence) and A is merely "Achieved [the required standard]". The other passing grade is M.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, my High School in Pennsylvania did in fact use E instead of F. This was in the mid 2000s.